# JavaScript - Difference between two dates in days or less

Tags: javascript, datetime, typescript, localization

I have 2 dates that I would like to have the difference between them in days and if less than a one day simply show "less than a day".

```
remainingTime() {
  // Scientific notation of 8.64e+7
  const DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS = 8.64 * (10 ** 7);

  const date1 = new Date('2019-02-28T01:22:06.671Z').getTime();
  const date2 = new Date('2019-02-28T04:01:06.671Z').getTime();

  const differenceInMS = date2 - date1;

  const days = Math.floor(differenceInMS / DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS);
  return (days > 1) ? `They have ${days} days` : (days === 1) ? `They have ${days} day` : `you have less than a day left`;
}
```

Is this way correct if localization is taken into account?

what exactly is the difference between `getTime ()`, `getMilliseconds ()` and `getUTCMilliseconds ()`?

Comment: You can use Exponentiation number notation for numbers. eg `8.64 * 10 ** 7 === 8.64e7` or '8.64E7'  also `**` has precedence over `*` so you don't need the `()` around `10 ** 7`

Comment: What localization? Your code isn't internationalized.

Comment: Considering that you have hard-coded English strings, this is obviously not correct, taking localization into account...

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](/help/on-topic) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good to me. I think `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24` would be more intuitive than the scientific notation, but either way gets the job done.

The script doesn't actually take localization into account because `Date`'s `getTime` method is not localized. To account for time zone, you'd want to get the "timezone offset" of the user's location. (Note that `getTimezoneOffset` returns a number of minutes, and that number isn't a property of the date object but just an indication of what timezone the code is running in.)

As for the other methods
 - `getTime` returns the actual "timestamp", a big integer showing how many milliseconds have passed since the 60s ended in London
 - `getUTCMilliseconds` is just the last three digits of that timestamp (ie how many milliseconds it's been since the last full second since the "epoch", as it's called.)
 - Leaving out the `UTC` bit (as in `getMilliseconds`,  or in any of the similar `get` methods, excepting `getTime`) makes javascript calculate the local version for you (and in the case of milliseconds, I'd be pretty surprised if it were different from the universal version.)

...You can see the whole buffet on MDN:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Date.prototype_Methods